# I've run out of money in King's Bounty: The Legend

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend

I've played King's Bounty a lot. I'm in the "Demonic" setting now with fire and lava everywhere. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of money left. Every time I encounter enemies I lose a large amount of my own stack.

I now know that a good strategy (if not *the* best) would have been to invest in resurrection with a human army. Unfortunately I did not do that.

I will run out of units in about 2 or 3 fights. I don't have much cash left. What can I do?

So far I've seen two possibilities: dying a lot, then going back **all the way** (very long) to fight the same monsters over and over again until I defeat them. I won't – this is a game, it's supposed to be fun, and this would be a major pain.

The second possibility would be to cheat – there is a cheat that allows you to create money out of thin air. But this will make the game boring as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that either your army is just too weak or you are too careless about your units. **You are not supposed to lose a great deal of your army in each battle**; on the contrary, in like 80-90% of my battles I haven't lost a single unit*. This means I lose almost no gold on replenishing my army after a fight.

How to do it?

- Take out the enemy's ranged units first, and after they have no ranged units left just keep your distance while shooting with your own ranged. Work on preventing the enemy from reaching your own units (for example, by using slowing spell or summoned units). *Do not advance your melee units until you have to*. My army composition is usually 2-3 ranged units - i.e. about half.
- Work on making your spells / rage abilities strong (via skills, items etc), they are a great way of causing damage without endangering your own troop. It's okay if you only focus on rage abilities or only focus on spells, but don't neglect both.
- Do not engage in battles where the enemy army is too strong. Do not ask yourself "can I defeat this army", instead ask "what price will I pay for defeating this army". What is "too strong"? Well it depends. When giving you the "danger level" the game does not consider your spells and abilities, so the stronger you are in that regard, the tougher fights you can handle.

In addition to all this, resurrection can be extremely beneficial. Unfortunately there isn't a lot in King's Bounty: The Legend which can do that (a lot more options in the Armored Princess expansion, fortunately). Inquisitors and the Resurrection spell are the main (if not only) things that can revive units. Remember that you can use the "gift" spell on your inquisitors to allow them to repeatedly use their resurrection ability. Also keep in mind the inquisitor's resurrection can revive level 5 monsters, which the resurrection spell can't.

*In normal difficulty, not higher difficulty levels

Comment: I never used resurrection tbh and made it through the game just fine. :) +1 for strategy advice

Comment: I face Devils and Succubus, the Devils teleport and the succubus swap my units with some of their large stack melee units

Comment: @Eric sounds like [a topic for a different question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=How%20to%20deal%20with%20demons%20in%20King's%20Bounty&tags=kings-bounty-the-legend)! Seriously you should ask it, I know I already have an answer and others might have even better answers for you.

Answer (score 1):

Kings Bounty is not that hard if you don't waste your units and money, save and loads don't make you a weaker player, you have to learn from the mistakes made in a battle and don't repeat them again.

Another option beside those you already have is to **finish quests that give money as a reward**.

If you finished all of them, pretty much you made a few mistakes with your character and army. The difficulty of KB is increased once you get deeper into the story. I would suggest **loading some old saves so that you don't have to repeat the game over**.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I think this addition is relevant.

Save often, and don't delete saves unnecessarily.  Normally I only keep 3 save files in any given game, but for this game, you really want to leave options open to revert back to exactly the right moment in the game where you think you made a major mistake.